# Isolating some CPU cores reduce average CPU usage of game servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, cpu, games

Hardware: FX8320 (8 cores) @ 4.4GHz, 16GB

I run 10 TF2 game servers. Few days ago I isolated some CPU cores with line in linux grub config:

```
isolcpus=5-7
```

The strange thing - individual CPU cores seems to be loaded for ~50% - which is same as before, when all 8 cores were available. And average CPU usage is less than before. Look at [the graphs from Zabbix](https://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0429/h_1430335119_7057412_b1f6c919fc.png).

Servers seem to work fine, no visible performance drop. Any way this can be explained?

Comment: Are you sure the load is constant? Maybe you've had less players today.

Comment: thats why I provide graphics with player count, which indicate nearly same amount of players in same time when CPU load was measured…